# row random sampling in r

Tags: r, random

I want to sample 60 random rows 1000 times with the `replace=TRUE` and calculate the correlation coefficients between first and second columns in each sample.

I don't know how to sample row randomly, so I tried to sample 60 numbers in 1:60, and matched the row numbers.
The row data is 60x2 matrix which is called `data1`.

My code is

```
k <- list()
data.sam <- list()

set.seed(1)

for (j in 1:60){
  for (i in 1:1000){
  k[[i]] <- sample(1:60, 60, replace = TRUE)
  }
  data.sam[[i]][j,] <- data1[k[[i]][j],]

  corr <- vector()
  corr[i] <- cor(data.sam[[i]][,1],data.sam[[i]][,2])
}
```

And the statement is showed:

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the `j` variable is doing very much. Your indexing is already vectorized by k[[i], so you don't need two loops explicitly. Also don't reset the `corr` variable inside the loop.

Instead, I might write:

```
data1 <- matrix(rnorm(120), 60,2)

for (i in 1:1000){
  k[[i]] <- sample(1:60, 60, replace = TRUE)
  data.sam[[i]] <- data1[k[[i]],]

  corr[i] <- cor(data.sam[[i]][,1],data.sam[[i]][,2])
}
```

Which give this:

```
hist(corr)
```

[image: histogram]